# how to display data horizontally in single table data using laravel and vue js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

> I have 2 table
> table 1

```
________________
| name_id  name |   
| 1       john  |
| 2      heaven |
|_______________|
```

> table 2

```
_______________________
| id name_id  product |   
| 1    1         bag  |
| 2    1       shoes  |
|_____________________|
```

> I WANT TO DISPLAY IT LIKE THIS

```
__________________________
| # | name    |  product  |   
| 1 |  John   | bag,shoes |
| 2 | Heaven  |           |
|___|_________|___________|
```

> I dont know how to do it in my controller
> Controller.php

```
       $data = DB::table('table1')
          ->leftjoin('table2','table2.name_id','=','table1.name_id')
             ->select('table1.*','table2.*')
          ->get();
    
    return $data
```

> this how I display my data in table
>
> Myvue js

```
methods:{

  loaddata(){

   axios.get('api/data').then(({data}){
  (this.alldata = data)
})

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try working with `GROUP_CONCAT`

For example like that:

```
DB::table('table1')
->leftjoin('table2','table2.name_id','=','table1.name_id')
->select('table1.*', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(table2.product SEPARATOR ', ') AS products'))
->groupBy('table1.name_id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You left out `::table` from `DB`

`DB::('table1')` => `DB::table('table1')`

```php
$data = DB::table('table1')
            ->leftJoin('table2', 'table1.name_id', '=', 'table2.name_id')
            ->select('table1.*', 'table2.*')
            ->get();
```

Comment: this is the same what I did

Comment: You never called table after DB:: @azakura

Comment: Oh I forgot  but the thing is I want to display it like in the 3rd table